# Handling events in wxPython

Tags: events, wxpython

How to pass an argument to an event handler in wxPython?

Here's my code:

```
    def close_handler(event):
        baz(foo)

    ...

    foo = 'bar'
    frame.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, close_handler)
```

How to pass foo to `close_handler()` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have `close_handler` create a second event-handling function that uses `foo`:

```
def close_handler(foo):
    return lambda event: baz(foo)

foo = 'bar'
frame.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, close_handler(foo))
```

Here `lambda event: baz(foo)` is an anonymous function that calls `baz(foo)`, silently discarding the `event` argument. Or you could pass it to `baz` if you wanted: `lambda event: baz(foo, event)`.

You could also write this without using `lambda` like so:

```
def close_handler(foo):
    def event_handler(event):
        return baz(foo)

    return event_handler
```

Answer (score 4):

```
import functools

def close_handler(event, foo):
    baz(foo)

foo = 'bar'
func = functools.partial(close_handler, foo=foo)
frame.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, func)
```

Or to conserve some space:

```
import functools

def close_handler(event, foo):
    baz(foo)

frame.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, functools.partial(close_handler, foo='bar'))
```